# Missing URI template variable 'idFamille' for method parameter of type int

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have created an APi which retrieve data from a database. My API is globally functioning excepting one request, where I get the error of the title.

I don't understand because I have some other requests writed in the same way and only this one is not functionning

This is my REST services (VarianteRestServices)

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class VarianteRestServices {

    @Autowired
    private VarianteRepository varianteRepository;


    //This function is not working
    @GetMapping(value="/listVariantesByFamille/{id}")
    public List<Variante> listVariantesByFamilles(@PathVariable(name="idFamille") int idFamille){
        return varianteRepository.findVarianteByFamille(idFamille);
    }
```

And this is my Repository :

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface VarianteRepository extends JpaRepository<Variante, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Variante> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT v FROM Variante v WHERE v.famille.id = ?1")
    @RestResource(path = "/byFamille")
    public List<Variante> findVarianteByFamille(@Param("idF") Integer famille);
}
```

I call my API like this : http://localhost:8080/listVariantesByFamille/4

If anybody know why I get this error ?

Comment: `@GetMapping(value="/listVariantesByFamille/{id}")` so `@PathVariable(name="idFamille")`  needs to be `@PathVariable(name="id")`

Comment: @Alan Hay I was knowing that it was a stupid mistake.. thank you man